# Converting array of integer (big endian) values from modbus to Double

Tags: node.js, endianness, modbus

Using a siemens PAC2200(power measurement) connected to an IoT module (advantech wise 4060).

This sends the data via modbus protocol to an REST endpoint.

Currently I'm parsing some values fine (2 registers), but when using 4 registers I am unsure if the values are correct. the below way is incorrect for the 4 registers.

```
// 2 register parsing 
// first is LSB second is MSB
function parseValue(low, high) {

    var buffer = Buffer.alloc(4);
    buffer.writeUInt16BE(high, 0);
    buffer.writeUInt16BE(low, 0);

    return buffer.readFloatBE(0)
}
```

So basically.. I cannot get the below values (data,data2) parsed to a proper number and I could use some help:)

```
var data = [25392,53544,16771,7275]

var data2= [25392,54354,16771,7679]
```

Values that have pulled don't seem to be updating as it should be a cumulative number, which didn't happen when I logged the values

Comment: Your code looks wrong, even for floats, change `buffer.writeUInt16BE(low, 0);` to `buffer.writeUInt16BE(low, 2);` (currently the second write is overwriting the first). The Modbus standard does not define a format for doubles so the encoding differs. Can you please let us know which registers you are reading and what you expect the result to be? (had a quick look at the PAC2200 manual but could not spot info on the encoding used).

Comment: Hey @Brits, Life saver! Ended up doing the following: `var buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(8); buffer.writeUInt16BE(high, 0); buffer.writeUInt16BE(low, 0); buffer.writeUInt16BE(high2, 2); buffer.writeUInt16BE(low2, 2);` You'd say the original question code wouldnt work, but somehow it does for the 2 regsister data.

Comment: Take a [look at this](https://runkit.com/embed/wdu94zf0s4h6) for an explanation of my previous comment.

Comment: That clarifies. Thanks